# How to get values from logs into java list? <hibernate>

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

**Is this possible to take that values from console:**
[image]
**and save them into java list/map?**

I printed that logs in that way:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

My query:

```
@Transactional
public String executeSQL(String[] split){
    SessionFactory hibernateFactory = someService.getHibernateFactory();
    String message = null;
    int rows = 0;
    EntityManager entityManager = hibernateFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction utx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String query = split[i];
        try {
            utx.begin();
            Query query1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
            rows = query1.executeUpdate();
            utx.commit();
            try{
                resultList = query1.getResultList();
                resultList.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            message = "Success \n{ ["+rows+"] <--- affected rows}";
        }catch (PersistenceException e){
            utx.rollback();
            message = (((SQLGrammarException)e.getCause()).getSQLException()).getMessage();
        }
    }
    entityManager.close();
    return message;
}
```

I know how to save values into list as you can see but i can't extract columns... because there is no information about columns name. In that logs columns have names and also columns have type, that informations would be usefull for me.

Comment: Can you please share the rest of your code? For example the actual native query is missing. Also take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-query-to-custom-class

Comment: I edited code. What do you mean my query is missing?

Comment: I think you fail to understand the purpose of Hibernate. Hibernate is an ORM which means it maps Java POJOs into database tables vise versa. The information you're referring to are your entity objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option how it could be implemented is [Logback Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)
Once you will have logs into appender you can implement filtering and whatever you need.

1.Add dependency to logback-classic

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2.Add logback.xml to resources

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="list" class="com.test.ListAppender"/>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="list"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

3.Implement Appender class

```
package com.test;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private static List<ILoggingEvent> eventList = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
        eventList.add(event);
    }

    public List<ILoggingEvent> getEventList() {
        return eventList;
    }
}
```

4.Test your code

```
package com.test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    static ListAppender listAppender = new ListAppender();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello World");
        listAppender.getEventList().forEach(entry -> System.out.println("print log from list:" + entry));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```